# str.extract starting from the back in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, series

I have a DataFrame with thousands of rows and two columns like so:

```
                                          string       state
0      the best new york cheesecake rochester ny          ny
1      the best dallas bbq houston tx random str          tx
2   la jolla fish shop of san diego san diego ca          ca
3                                   nothing here          dc
```

For each state, I have a regular expression of all city names (in lower case) structured like `(city1|city2|city3|...)` where the order of the cities is arbitrary (but can be changed if needed). For example, the regular expression for the state of New York contains both `'new york'` and `'rochester'` (and likewise `'dallas'` and `'houston'` for Texas, and `'san diego'` and `'la jolla'` for California).

I want to find out what the last appearing city in the string is (for observations 1, 2, 3, 4, I'd want `'rochester'`, `'houston'`, `'san diego'`, and `NaN` (or whatever), respectively).

I started off with `str.extract` and was trying to think of things like reversing the string but have reached an impasse.

Thanks so much for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.findall.html), but if no match get empty `list`, so need apply. Last select last item of string by `[-1]`:

```
cities = r"new york|dallas|rochester|houston|san diego"

print (df['string'].str.findall(cities)
                   .apply(lambda x: x if len(x) >= 1 else ['no match val'])
                   .str[-1])
0       rochester
1         houston
2       san diego
3    no match val
Name: string, dtype: object
```

(Corrected >= 1 to > 1.)

Another solution is a bit hack - add no match string to start of each string by  [`radd`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.radd.html) and add this string to cities too:

```
a = 'no match val'
cities = r"new york|dallas|rochester|houston|san diego" + '|' + a

print (df['string'].radd(a).str.findall(cities).str[-1])
0       rochester
1         houston
2       san diego
3    no match val
Name: string, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

```
cities = r"new york|dallas|..."

def last_match(s):
    found = re.findall(cities, s)
    return found[-1] if found else ""

df['string'].apply(last_match)
#0    rochester
#1      houston
#2    san diego
#3
```